# How can I update a variable in database with max date?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

How can I increase a variable in database with max date and input variable. I mean like this:

```
$update = $db->prepare("UPDATE errortable SET error_count = error_count+1 WHERE input_verb =? and max(date_col)");
```

Comment: Did you tried with a subquery? UPDATE errortable SET error_count = error_cout + 1 WHERE input_verb = ? AND date_col = (SELECT max(date_col) FROM errortable)

Comment: no . i ll try ty so much